# Sitecore can't publish in visual studio. How do I solve this error?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sitecore

Whenever I try to publish sitecore in visual studio i receive this error

```
An error occurred loading a configuration file: Directory
 'C:\sitecore\Consortium\Consortium.WebApp\obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\App_Config'
 does not exist. Failed to start monitoring file change
```

I'
ve googled and can't find any reason why this would be or how to fix it.  I created the app_config folder and it just deletes it on publish and displays the error.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You must include the `App_Config` folder in your project and make sure the Build Action for each file is set to `Content`.
Should be alright then..

[image]

Comment: I don't have an app_config.  I have an app_config_master